# Как вывести картинку из common в yii2?

Tags: yii2

Пытаюсь вывести картинку из базы во вьюшке, путь до папки с картинкой такой common/uploads.

но ссылка почему-то битая. Подскажите пожалуйста, что тут не так?

Comment: Картинки нужно хранить в доступной для web директории, то есть в папке `web`.

Comment: А как можно дать доступ common папку

Comment: Никак. Ты можешь написать какой-нибудь action который будет принимать как get-параметр имя файла, по этому имени будет сам брать файл из `common/uploads/` и отдавать клиенту. В правилах urlManager прописать что-то типа `'common/uploads/<file:[\w_-]+\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)' => 'module/controller/get-file'`, в контроллере экшин будет `public function actionGetFile($file) { ... }`

Comment: Есть выход, если вы с помощью htaccess все настроили. Если вы уже с помощью apache или nginx настроили корневую директорию, то никак. Напишите, как вы настроили сам YII и дальше уже будет видно

Answer (score 0):

Все что отдает веб-сервер должно быть доступно через папку `frontend/web`, на которую он настроен. Один из вариантов создать симлинк из `common/uploads`, в `frontend/web/uploads`.

И не забудьте про безопасность. Для `web/uploads` в конфигах веб-сервера нужно запретить выполнение php-файлов.